# Cannot find incanter-datasets or -stats jars in clojars or maven

Tags: maven, clojure, incanter, clojars

I am experiencing something very peculiar while attempting to use incanter. In my lein project.clj file I set up dependencies for -datasets and -stats (and core, etc.), then do 'lein deps', which reports that these jars are not found in maven or clojar repos. When I look in ~/.m2/repositories/incanter there are folders for 1.5.4 datasets & stats but they contain no jars. All the other incanter packages have 1.5.4 jars and the older versions such as 1.4.1. Hopefully someone can shed light on these missing items.

Comment: can you show excerpt from your `project.clj`?

Comment: This is what I have.     :dependencies [ [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
       [org.clojure/math.combinatorics "0.0.3"]
       [incanter/incanter "1.5.4"]
      [incanter/incanter-core "1.5.4"]      
      [incanter/incanter-charts "1.5.4"]
      [incanter/incanter-io "1.5.4"] [incanter/incanter-stats "1.5.4"]
      [incanter/incanter-datasets "1.5.4"]
   :main genetics1.core

Comment: btw, if you're using `[incanter/incanter "1.5.4"]` as dependency, then you don't need to specify any other incanter's dependencies - they are already included into it...

Answer (score 1):

there is no separate `incanter-stats` & `incanter-datasets` modules.  The namespace `incanter.stats` is in the `incanter-core` package, while `incanter.datasets` is in the `incanter.io` package.

Full list of modules you can find in the `modules` directory on the github, or in my [presentation about Incanter](http://alexott.net/common/incanter-denver/#/sec-4).

You need to add following to your `project.clj`:

```
:dependencies [[incanter/incanter-core "1.5.4"] 
               [incanter/incanter-io "1.5.4"]
              ...]
```

and use following in your `ns` declaration:

```
(:use [incanter core io stats datasets]))
```

P.S. I think, that main source of confusion is separation of namespaces (incanter.core, incanter.io, etc.) into packages (modules) that are distributed via clojar...

Comment: Thank you Alex. Does this mean that in my clojure code I can change this: (:use [incanter core io stats datasets]) to just this: (:use [incanter core io])?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the snippets for project.clj & namespace declaration...

Comment: Again thank you for a clear explanation. I unconsciously assumed the namespaces and the clojar package structure would be the same.

Comment: the primary reason for separation was to minimize dependencies - some people want only stats, etc. and don't want to get charts, mongodb, etc.